# Twitter Typeahead square brackets

Tags: typeahead

I have a `Twitter Typeahead` enabled control. It uses `bloodhound` to preload some data, which consists of results like this:

```
[1996] Something
[1996] Something Else
[1996] Even more
[1996] Still more
[1996] Thats it
```

The control is set to display results after 3 characters.

If I type `199`, the results return correctly, however, if I type `[199` or even `[1996`, I get no results. The only time I get the results is if I close the bracket, and type `[1996]`.

Has anyone else experienced this? Or knows the issue?

Answer (score 2):

did you ever get this resolved? If not, try the following;

```
var normalize = function(str) {
  $.each(charMap, function(chars, normalized) {
    var regex = new RegExp('[' + chars + ']', 'gi');
    str = str.replace(regex, normalized);
  });

  return str;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/531)

Comment: No I haven't - Although I had to find another implementation to resolve my issue! Will definitely keep this in mind in the future.